# Unable to run a plain Java Wiremock

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm an absolute beginner to Wiremock, Maven and stuff. I just want to run Wiremock server in my Java program. I got Maven installed and used [this](https://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/) and [this](https://wiremock.org/docs/java-usage/) guides to try and get Wiremock running inside my java code. My `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<project>
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.mycode</groupId>
     <artifactId>test</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <properties>
          <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
          <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
     </properties>
     <dependencies>
          <dependency>
               <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
               <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
               <version>2.35.0</version>
               <scope>test</scope>  
          </dependency>
     </dependencies>    
</project>
```

And my Java code which resides in a file called testWiremock.java looks like this:

```
public class testWiremock{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          WireMockServer wiremockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(8080));
          wireMockServer.start();
          System.out.println("Server running successfully!");
          wreMockServer.stop();
     }
}
```

When I try to compile it with `mvn compile`, I get the following error:

```
ppgoodman@CWGXXXXQCL wiretest % mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO]
com.mycode:test
[INFO] Building test 1.0
[INFO]
[ jar ]---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6: resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/src/main/resources [INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/target/classes [INFO]
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO]
[ERROR] /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/src/main/java/testWiremock.java: [4,9] cannot find symbol symbol: class WireMockServer
location: class testWiremock
[ERROR] /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/src/main/java/testWiremock.java: [4,45] cannot find symbol symbol: class WireMockServer
location: class testWiremock
[ERROR] /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/src/main/java/testWiremock.java: [4,60] cannot find symbol symbol: method options()
location: class testWiremock
[INFO] 3 errors
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]
[INFO] Total time: 8.432 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2822-11-13T18:29:49-05:00
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: [ERROR] /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/src/main/java/testWiremock.java: [4,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]
symbol: class WireMockServer
[ERROR] location: class testwiremock
[ERROR] /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/src/main/java/testWiremock.java: [4,45] cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class WireMockServer
[ERROR] location: class testWiremock
wiretest-zsh-245x68
[ERROR] /Users/ppgoodman/Documents/programming/wiretest/src/main/java/testWiremock.java: [4,60] cannot find symbol [ERROR]
symbol: method options()
[ERROR] location: class testWiremock
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

What am I missing here? Do I have to have any imports? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please execute the command: `$> mvn clean package` Then we continue ...

Comment: @kladderradatsch thanks for the suggestion. I'm still getting the same 'cannot find symbol errrors'.

Comment: Remove `<scope>test</scope>` in your `pom.xml` because your main class is not in the test scope. That leads to the further question why do you use Wiremock in a class which is not a test? Don't do this!

Comment: @kladderradatsch I removed it. I'm still having the same problem. The reason for doing this is because I need to test some other component written as a separate stand alone program. I need a http server with good programmatic control over the output. Is there any other recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

WireMock is just for testing but you've put it into the implementation scope of your code base (i.e. in folder *src/main/java*) by referring to it in a main class. However, it cannot be available there because the dependency is equipped with `<scope>test</scope>`. Leave it as it is and configure WireMock in your test classes (i.e. in folder *src/test/java*) like the [WireMock's documentation](https://wiremock.org/docs/junit-jupiter/) shows it:

```
@WireMockTest(httpPort = 8080)
public class FixedPortDeclarativeWireMockTest {
    ...
}
```

That code snippet above has the same effect as what you did in the main class.

Comment: Actually what was missing was the two imports: `import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WiremockServer;` and `import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;` adding them made it work.

Comment: Please work with an IDE like **Eclipse** or **IDEA intelliJ** in which this is done automatically.